# Start package manager in Windows 10

Tags: packages, miktex

In Windows 10 there is no Start → Program anymore so [this method](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html) doesn't work anymore. Can you tell me the path of the package manager? I can't find it.

Comment: You should try typing "miktex" in the search (windows key + S).

Comment: @Werner I tried that already before posting here. It doesn't show me the package manager.

Comment: ...it might be called "mpm"...

Answer (score 10):

The [MiKTeX Package Manager](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html) for Windows is known under its abbreviation "MPM". You should be able to [find it under all applications](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-10/getstarted-find-all-your-apps-and-programs) by looking under "M":

[image]

Alternatively, you can also search for items and look for "MPM":

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 10 click on the Windows Logo. Then choose "All Apps". Scroll down to "M". There you can find an entry "MikTeX 2.9". Click on it and you will get the list of all MikTeX programs like Manual, Package Manager, Settings, Update ...

Answer (score 1):

The above answers (involving the search function) didn't work for me (for some reason) but I found it by locating the `.exe` file in the relevant folder, which in my case was:

`miktex\bin\x64\mpm_mfc_admin.exe`

Answer (score 0):

In my case,I found mpm under that directory as well *miktex\bin\x64\mpm.exe* , but I realized that the MPM is the same MikTeX console, that appears in Start>Programs>MikTeX> MikTex Console